# SonarQube failing on files filled only with comments

Tags: vb.net, tfs, sonarqube

I'm trying to analyze the code of a vb application in TFS.
I'm using SonarQube, with the TFS extension.

My issue is that, whenever SonarQube encounters a file which only has comments in it, it will fail with this message :

> ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>
> ERROR: Unable to register token in file the [filepath].vb
>
> ERROR: Caused by: 21 is not a valid line offset for pointer. File [filepath].vb has 20 character(s) at line 1

All the files have the .vb extension.

I would just remove these useless files from the repository but the code is not mine and there are over 15K files.

Is there a way to avoid crashing on this type of files ?
Or avoid analysing files filled with comments and empty lines ?